# HTML - Webpage example with body stretching down?

Tags: css, html

In Microsoft's homepage (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) you see the white background stretch all the way to the bottom and the sides in grey?

How do you that in an HTML/CSS? I mean, I've been trying but the DIV won't go all the way down...

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, their page has enough content to force the page to scroll. [Like this](http://jsbin.com/oherux/1)

If you don't have enough content, you can set the height of the div to 100%. The important thing to note here is that it will be 100% of its parent's height. That's why you have to set the html and body heights to 100% as well. [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/agorih/2)

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#contentDiv {
    height:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="contentDiv">my content here</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that the body and html file has 100% height aswell, cause 100% is what it gets from the current height of the parent element
so if you set, and html's parent is the window(document) that's why you get a full height

```
html,body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background:gray;
}
div{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background:red;
}
```

you will get a red page

Answer (score 0):

Set the height to %100 and sometimes setting the parent element to position:relative will set things straight. Post your html and css and we could help you better.